# Where do I ask Snort Network Intrusion Detection System (NIDS) questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Now am currently working with Snort, NIDS (Network Intrusion Detection System), I have asked questions related to this in Stack Overflow, Ask Ubuntu, Unix & Linux. But I did not get answers properly. Where do I ask such questions and in which community do I ask?

Comment: Which communities did you ask in?

Comment: "NDIS questions" is much too vague. Please tell us more about the sort of questions you have in mind, an example would be good.

Comment: I have asked in Stack Overflow , Unix & Linux , Ask Ubundu .. My questions are related to Snort in NIDS.

Comment: "related to Snort" is not enough. If you mean programming with "Snort" (no matter what it is) then it might fit Stack Overflow. Can't see how it's related to unix or Ask Ubuntu. (unless this whole thing is part of Ubuntu?)

Comment: related to snort, I mean here , to know more about snort ,testing snort rules , creating own snort rules, etc.

Comment: Sounds too specific to snort, so probably fits only in their own forums.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on what your question is, [Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com) may be suitable.

From our [site scope](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> IT Security Stack Exchange is for Information Security professionals to discuss protecting assets from threats and vulnerabilities. Topics include, but are not limited to:
>
> web app hardening, network security, social engineering, including phishing, risk management, policies, penetration testing, security tools, using cryptography, incident response, physically securing the office, datacentre, information assets etc.

This can include configuration of tools like Snort, usage etc. It probably isn't going to include how to install it or things like that which really aren't related to security.

I'd suggest first reading the existing questions there on Snort and other IDS and NIDS solutions to see the sort of things that work.

Answer (score 0):

Please direct your questions to the Snort mailing lists:  https://www.snort.org/community

As the community manager for Snort, (the above is correct. )

Comment: This confirms this question is off topic here, thanks.